# How to format and merge strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

I am trying to format and merge the strings (with sprintf) and then print them with printf. But it does not work, and I have no clue why.
The error is that string is not initialised.

```
int main() {
char wochentag[] = "Freitag";
int tag = 13;
char monat[] = "Mai";
int jahr = 1927;
char *string;
char *array=(char *) malloc(26*sizeof(char));
sprintf (string,"%s" "%d" "%s" "%d",wochentag,tag,monat,jahr);


printf("%s\n", string);
free(array);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question, but it looks like you need to enclose your format specifier in quotes. And `(* char)` is not a valid cast.

Comment: http://ideone.com/T9Cnxo

Comment: @Fabian - `array` is allocated but never used. `string` is used but never allocated. You see the problem?

Comment: Okay guys, thank you I finally got it!

Comment: You should not cast the return value of malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1025391

Comment: `char monat[] = "Mai"` is a worse choice than `const char *monat = "Mai"`, because the first declares a non-const char array.  The second can keep the string data in read-only memory, sharing storage with any other uses of the same string constant.

Comment: regarding the call to malloc():  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard as always 1.  Multiplying anything by ` results in no change.  Therefore the expression just clutters the code.   When calling malloc(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Where did the magic number 26 come from anyway? You should replace it with some meaningful constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fixes achieve what you're trying to do:

```
char *array=(char *) malloc(26*sizeof(char));
```

A pointer to char is `char*`, not `*char`.

```
char *array=(char *) malloc(26*sizeof(char));
sprintf (array,"%s %d %s",wochentag,tag,monat);
printf("%s\n", array);
```

Since you allocate memory to your `array` variable, that's what you should use in `sprintf` and `printf`, right? Also note that the correct use of `sprintf` is with quotation marks.

This is the fixed code:

```
int main() {
    char wochentag[] = "Freitag";
    int tag = 13;
    char monat[] = "Mai";
    int jahr = 1927;
    char *string;

    char *array=(char *) malloc(26*sizeof(char));
    sprintf (array,"%s %d %s",wochentag,tag,monat);

    printf("%s\n", array);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code compiles cleanly, removes code clutter, performs error checking, includes the needed header files, is appropriately indented for readability  and works correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char wochentag[] = "Freitag";
    int tag = 13;
    char monat[] = "Mai";
    int jahr = 1927;

    char *string=malloc(26);
    if( NULL == string)
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for 26 bytes failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    sprintf (string,"%s%d%s%d",wochentag,tag,monat,jahr);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```